# Getting same output for mysql command line when SQL input is redirected from file (Batch mode)

Tags: mysql

This appears to be simple, but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Here is a simple sql script:

```
   select c1 from t1 where c1='notPresent';
```

I execute it using interactive shell as in:

```
   mysql -u somebody -psomePassword myDatabase
   ...
   mysql> select c1 from t1 where c1='notPresent';

          Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I execute it as:

```
    mysql -u somebody -psomePassword myDatabase < myFile.sql
```

The output is:

```
        mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

**I know how to suppress this warning by saving the userId and password in my.cnf but I want to get the "Empty set" output too.**

The same with SQL Updates. When script is from a file, it does not display status as in number of row updated.

This is part of a bigger application. I have narrowed the problem to the above situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use triple-verbose mode to get full output in batch mode:

```
echo "show tables" | mysql -v -v -v test 

--------------
show tables
--------------

+--------------------+
| Tables_in_test     |
+--------------------+
| ........           |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Bye
```

I spotted this option when I looked at the help:

```
mysql --help

...

-v, --verbose       Write more. (-v -v -v gives the table output format).
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!!  Please update the answer to match the question.... in Batch mode.  It works but your example should be in batch mode where it does not work without giving -v twice.

Comment: Can you look at this question. Only reason I am disturbing you is that I have not received any suggestions and need to get this done quickly... 
 though it is a weekend! 
 Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244107/configuring-my-cnf-in-home-directory-for-multiple-databases-does-not-work-work

Comment: But what if I only want the "rows in set" output and not the rest of the verbosity?

Comment: @BenSlade, If none of the existing verbosity levels for the mysql client work for you, I think you may have to filter it through `grep` or similar tool, or else develop your own client.

Comment: @BenSlade, Hey man, don't shoot the messenger.